# How can I get command output from ShellStream without it timing out?

Tags: c#, ssh

I use [ssh.net](https://www.ssh.com/) to execute commands in C# 
but the results returned from each command come at different times.

I used thread but it takes timeout with a specific value.
I need to get the output at the moment it comes

My code:

```
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    string Username = "xxxxxxxx";
    string Password = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    string IP = "xxxxxxxxxx";
    int Port = xxxxxxxxx;

    SshClient client = new SshClient(IP, Port, Username, Password);
    client.Connect();
    var shell = client.CreateShellStream("xxxx", 5000, 10000, 10000, 10000, 40072);

    string output = ArrangeData("stelnet xxxxxxxx", shell);
    output += ArrangeData("cmd1", shell);
    output += ArrangeData("cmd2", shell);
    output += ArrangeData("cmd3", shell);
}

public static string ArrangeData(string cmd, ShellStream sh)
{
    StreamReader reader = null;
    reader = new StreamReader(sh);
    sh.Flush();
    sh.WriteLine(cmd);

    ---->Thread.Sleep(timeout);

    string output = reader.ReadToEnd();
    return output;
}
```

The current solution is time out in thread

However, I need to remove this timeout as I do not know when it responds to my commands.

Comment: what do you want to achieve ?

Comment: some commands "configuration" on router